# Android - Fragment with gridView collapse when soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, gridview, keyboard

I have an `Activity` with a ViewPager with two `Fragments`:

**My problem**

When I open soft keyboard on `FragmentA with Edittext`, the `fragment` it's collapsed, but only when I `uncomment` the `GridView`on `FragmentB`.

I tried all options on `AndroidManifest.xml` using: `android:windowSoftInputMode=`

```
  <activity
      //.......
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" />
```

I tried to put it programmatically on fragments and Activity:

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

And it doesn't work, always Activity/Fragments it's collapsed...

**If I comment or remove the `GridView` on the `XML`, Works fine**

Then... the problem? It's the `GridView`, but I need that...

**FragmentB code with GridView**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="#64aca89c">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Any suggestions?